# В чём проблема установки gem sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite, ruby, gems

**Прилагаю код проблемы, которая мне высветилась в консоли. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема?**

```
$ gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-include=/c:/sqlite/ --with-sqlite3-lib=/c:/sqlite/.libs/
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-sqlite3-include=c:/sqlite/ --with-sqlite3-lib=c:/sqlite/.libs/'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12/ext/sqlite3
"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe" -r ./siteconf20161228-9340-d3s9zm.rb extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-include=c:/sqlite/ --with-sqlite3-lib=c:/sqlite/.libs/
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... yes
checking for rb_proc_arity()... yes
checking for rb_integer_pack()... yes
checking for sqlite3_initialize()... yes
checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... yes
checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... no
checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... yes
checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_prepare_v2()... yes
checking for sqlite3_int64 in sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_uint64 in sqlite3.h... yes
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.12/mkmf.log

current directory: d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12/ext/sqlite3
make "DESTDIR=" clean
Makefile:264: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

current directory: d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12/ext/sqlite3
make "DESTDIR="
Makefile:264: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12 for inspection.
Results logged to d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.12/gem_make.out
```

**В mkmf лог упала следующая ошибка:**

```
package configuration for sqlite3 is not found
find_header: checking for sqlite3.h... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <sqlite3.h>
/* end */

--------------------

find_library: checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'pthread_create' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))pthread_create; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.      -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void pthread_create();
17: int t(void) { pthread_create(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

find_library: checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_libversion_number' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_libversion_number; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_libversion_number();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_libversion_number(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_proc_arity()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_proc_arity; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_integer_pack()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_integer_pack; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_initialize()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_initialize' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_initialize; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_initialize();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_initialize(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_backup_init()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_backup_init' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_backup_init; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_backup_init();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_backup_init(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_column_database_name()... -------------------- no

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_column_database_name' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_column_database_name; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
C:\Users\green\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfrMZPf.o: In function `t':
d:\Program Files\Ruby23-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\sqlite3-1.3.12\ext\sqlite3/conftest.c:17: undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_database_name'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_column_database_name();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_column_database_name(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_enable_load_extension()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_enable_load_extension' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_enable_load_extension; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_enable_load_extension();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_enable_load_extension(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_load_extension()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:16:57: error: 'sqlite3_load_extension' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:16:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))sqlite3_load_extension; return !p; }
/* end */

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     printf("%p", &t);
12:   }
13: 
14:   return 0;
15: }
16: extern void sqlite3_load_extension();
17: int t(void) { sqlite3_load_extension(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for sqlite3_open_v2()... -------------------- yes

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0/x64-mingw32" -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0"/ruby/backward -I"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/include/ruby-2.3.0" -I. -Ic:/sqlite -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -L"d:/Program Files/Ruby23-x64/lib" -Lc:/sqlite/.libs/ -L.     -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby230 -lsqlite3 -lpthread  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
```

Comment: что упало в указанный mkmf.log?

Comment: @Etki вставил столько, сколько вместилось

Comment: а как вы руби на компьютер устанавливали?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman через rubyinstaller.

Comment: попробуйте использовать railsinstaller. в нем уже есть sqlite.